# Converting String 'yyyy-mm' in two localdatetime java 8+

Tags: java, string, converters, localdate

I have a string that constrains a month and year ex: `2019-02` and I need to converter in two `LocalDateTime`. I need an first day and the last day of month 02.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class:

```
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.parse("2019-02");
LocalDate startDate = yearMonth.atDay(1); // 2019-02-01
LocalDate endDate = yearMonth.atEndOfMonth(); // 2019-02-28
```

You can then convert to `LocalDateTime` e.g. if you need start of day time:

```
LocalDateTime startDayTime = startDate.atStartOfDay(); // 2019-02-01T00:00
```

Comment: This is exactly the that i am lookig for, thanks a lot Karol!